# An issue with Pdflatex (pdflatex (file lmmi7): Font lmmi7 at 600 not found)

Tags: pdftex, lyx, lmodern

I go directly to my problem. Recently, after a clean install of Ubuntu 18.04 and Mathematica 12, I get the below error when I "compile using pdflatex" the document in Lyx.

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file lmmi7): Font lmmi7 at 600 not found
```

The problem appears when I select Latin Modern Roman font, by using default font everything goes well. Would anybody please help me? 
The complete log is

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.6.24)  25 JUN 2019 01:00
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**Effective_Potential.tex
(./Effective_Potential.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 7 language(s) loaded.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) (/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lm/lmodern.sty
Package: lmodern 2009/10/30 v1.6 Latin Modern Fonts
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/lmr/m/n on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/m/it --> OML/lmm/m/it on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/m/n --> OMS/lmsy/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/lmex/m/n on input line 25.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/b/it --> OML/lmm/b/it on input line 27.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/b/n --> OMS/lmsy/b/n on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/lmex/m/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> OT1/lmss/m/n on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> OT1/lmr/m/it on input line 33.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/lmtt/m/n on input line 34.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> OT1/lmss/bx/n on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> OT1/lmr/bx/it on input line 37.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/lmtt/m/n on input line 38.
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX package
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def
File: t1enc.def 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 48.
)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2015/03/17 v1.2c Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks14
\inpenc@posthook=\toks15
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latin9.def
File: latin9.def 2015/03/17 v1.2c Input encoding file
)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
Package: babel 2018/02/14 3.18 The Babel package
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/switch.def
File: switch.def 2018/02/14 3.18 Babel switching mechanism
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf
Language: english 2017/06/06 v3.3r English support from the babel system
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
File: babel.def 2018/02/14 3.18 Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count87
\U@D=\dimen103
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def)
\bbl@dirlevel=\count88
)
\l@british = a dialect from \language\l@english 
\l@UKenglish = a dialect from \language\l@english 
\l@canadian = a dialect from \language\l@american 
\l@australian = a dialect from \language\l@british 
\l@newzealand = a dialect from \language\l@british 
))
No file Effective_Potential.aux.
\openout1 = `Effective_Potential.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+lmr on input line 10.
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lm/t1lmr.fd
File: t1lmr.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OT1+lmr on input line 13.
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lm/ot1lmr.fd
File: ot1lmr.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OML+lmm on input line 13.
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lm/omllmm.fd
File: omllmm.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OMS+lmsy on input line 13.

(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lm/omslmsy.fd
File: omslmsy.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OMX+lmex on input line 13.

(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lm/omxlmex.fd
File: omxlmex.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `lmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <10> on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `lmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `lmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 13.
[1

{/home/vahid/.texlive2017/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./Eff
ective_Potential.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1076 strings out of 494847
 13885 string characters out of 6179080
 66398 words of memory out of 5000000
 4429 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 18403 words of font info for 26 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 59 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 24i,4n,23p,200b,113s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file lmmi7): Font lmmi7 at 600 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: you have a `pdftex.map` in your home directory (see the end of the log-file) that probably shadows the system map-file. Rename it to e.g. pdftex.mapori and try again.

Comment: Wow! It worked! Yesterday, I was struggling with this issue for hours. You saved me just by a master trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a `pdftex.map` in your home directory (see the end of the log-file) that probably shadows the system map-file (that can happen if one use `updmap` instead of `updmap-sys`.

Rename it to e.g. pdftex.mapori and try again.

If it works, you can delete it, and other map-files in `/home/vahid/.texlive2017/texmf-var/fonts/map` too.